# Django serializer update all

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

When adding a definition for update in my serializer, do I have to put each field in or is there a way to do "any" or "all"?

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.id = validated_data.get('id', instance.id)
    instance.user.id = validated_data.get('user_id', instance.user.id)
    instance.city = validated_data.get('city', instance.city)
    # instance all fields?
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Answer (score 5):

1. first pop keys that should not be updated like id.

   `validated_data.pop('id')`
2. Use a loop.

   `for key, value in validated_data.items():
        setattr(instance, key, value)
   instance.save()`